# Setting a step's parameters by default in Kettle Pentaho

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I want to set the 'Text File Input' step's default 'encoding' to 'UTF-8' so that every time I drag the step onto the canvas it is automatically populated. How would I configure this?